# In Blackett's cloud chamber why couldn't an alpha particle bounce off a nitrogen atom knocking a proton off of it?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

I was reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton#History) which said

> In 1919 Rutherford assumed that the alpha particle merely knocked a proton out of nitrogen, turning it into carbon. After observing Blackett's cloud chamber images in 1925, Rutherford realized that the alpha particle was absorbed

I looked around for the Blackett's cloud chamber experiment and then found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Blackett#) which said

> He asked Blackett to use a cloud chamber to find visible tracks of this disintegration, and by 1925, he had taken 23,000 photographs showing 415,000 tracks of ionized particles. Eight of these were forked, and this showed that the nitrogen atom-alpha particle combination had formed an atom of fluorine, which then disintegrated into an isotope of oxygen 17 and a proton.

Then I found this image of the tracks in the cloud chamber on some other website.
[image]

Here I'm assuming the two forks are the ones circled in red
[image]

How did they know the alpha particle had to combine with nitrogen from this? Couldn't this picture still be explained with the alpha particle knocking off a proton from nitrogen (the light path im guessing) and the alpha particle continuing to move on the other path? Should it form three tracks instead of two in that case then? One for the proton, one for the alpha particle and one for the carbon as well as the carbon should be negatively charged so propanol can condense around it?

Comment: These questions seem to be addressed in the paper which is the source of your photographs: [Blackett, "The ejection of protons from nitrogen nuclei, photographed by the Wilson method," Proceedings of the Royal Society A, volume 107, issue 742, page 349 (1925)](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1925.0029).

Comment: i got the photos from https://www.lindahall.org/about/news/scientist-of-the-day/patrick-m-s-blackett/ will check out the paper

Comment: @rob yes that answers it, they expected 3 paths but only got 2 disproving what I asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How these alpha absorption events were identified is well-explained in Blackett's subsequent 1925 paper on ["The ejection of protons from nitrogen nuclei, photographed by the Wilson method"](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1925.0029):

> But amongst these normal forks due to elastic collisions, eight have been found of a strikingly different type. … These eight tracks undoubtedly represent the ejection of a proton from a nitrogen nucleus. It was to be expected that a photograph of such an event would show an alpha-ray track branching into three. The ejected proton, the residual nucleus from which it has been ejected, and the alpha-particle itself, might each have been expected to produce a track. These eight forks
> however branch only into two. The path of the first of the three bodies,
> the ejected proton, is obvious in each photograph. It consists of a fine straight track, along which the ionisation is clearly less than along an alpha-ray track, and must therefore be due to a particle of small charge and great velocity. The second of the two arms of the fork is a short track similar in appearance to the track of the nitrogen nucleus in a normal fork. Of a third arm to correspond to the track of the alpha-particle itself after the collision there is no sign. On the generally accepted view, due to the work of Rutherford, the nucleus of an atom is so small, and thus the potential at its surface so large, that a positively charged particle that has once penetrated its structure (and almost certainly an alpha-particle that ejects a proton must do so) cannot escape without acquiring kinetic energy amply sufficient to produce a visible track. As no such track exists the alpha-particle cannot escape. In ejecting a proton from a nitrogen nucleus the alpha-particle is therefore itself bound to the nitrogen nucleus

In summary,

- The kinematics of $\alpha + N \rightarrow \alpha + C + p$ scattering is such that three observable tracks ($\alpha, F, p$) should be produced, and these events only have two as expected for $\alpha + N \rightarrow  F + p$.
- The ionization the light tracks was measured with sufficient accuracy to show that they could not be alpha particles, and the range of the heavy tracks was consistent with nitrogen nuclei but not alpha particles.

Comment: An assigned reading in grad school was Chadwick's neutron-discovery paper, with the following instructor comment: "like most groundbreaking papers, this is one page long and applies conservation of momentum."